# Hibernate duplicate entry for key PRIMARY on merge

Tags: java, hibernate

i've an MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException in insert/update.

here my entity

sessions entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class SessionEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer dummyKey;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user",nullable = true,referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String userCode;

    @Column
    private Integer byteXmt;

    --- setter and getter ---
}
```

users entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    --- setter and getter ---

}
```

At startup UserEntity has zero record and SessionEntity has 2 records:

---

> dummyKey: 1
>
> userEntity: null
>
> userCode: bob
>
> byteXmt: 100

---

> dummyKey: 2
>
> userEntity: null
>
> userCode: bob
>
> byteXmt: 200

---

I need push into UserEntity only a record and in  SessionEntity the UserEntity reference:

```
List<SessionEntity> list = (List<SessionEntity>)  em.createNamedQuery("getAllRecords").getResultList();
for (SessionEntity sessionEntity : list) {
    String userCode = sessionEntity.getUserCode(); //"bob"
    UserEntity user = usersDAO.load(userCode); // first time is null
    if(user==null){
        user = new UserEntity();
        user.setId(userCode);
        user.setFirstName(sessionEntity.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(sessionEntity.getSecondName());
    }

    assert sessionEntity.getUserEntity()==null;
    sessionEntity.setUserEntity(user);
    em.merge(sessionEntity);
}
```

the error is:

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry 'bob ' for key 'PRIMARY'

i suppose inserts 2 times 'bob' record in UserEntity
how could use same record?

Comment: You set the id to "bob" in your code, but id's have to be unique in your database. So what exactly is your intention with inserting two times an entry with the same id? Do you want to update the old entry? Or is your id wrong used as a name?

Comment: yes, id is unique, i would like only a record with id = "bob" in UserEntity and 2 record in SessionEntity with userEntity = "bob"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is to persist the User object first. You create the User entity and associate it with the session entity, but I'm betting there is another path through the object graph that also gets to the User. And that is the second attempt to save the new object.